# Rendering a big dataset into four sections by PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, dataset

I have a perfomance question and a "good-way-to-code" question. I am using the Laravel framework because I a not that good in PHP. I want to get all the comments and group them in:

1. view all comments
2. approved comments
3. pending comments
4. spam

I want to do this in 4 tabs by using Twitter Bootstrap, so I need the data all at once.

I was thinking about 3 ways of doing this:

1. One database query and do PHP multiple foreach loops. First loop through all  comments and output it on the screen for "View all comments" tab. While looping I seperate the rows into the other datasets for the other tabs. The only way to do this is inside the View Template (in my opinion not a very beauthiful way).
2. Several database queries so I have datasets for each status right away.
3. do an AJAX request when clicking a tab: [loading new page in tabs using twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449063/loading-new-page-in-tabs-using-twitter-bootstrap)

Is there a better approach of doing this without harming perfomance? Or should I just try both scenarios and look how fast the page loads? I seriously tend to use the AJAX request when clicking a tab. Is that a good way of doing this?

Comment: Both options you listed read all the data into memory, the second option also involves multiple trips to the DB which will slow things down. Just how many results are we talking about here?

Comment: Well, it might be a few hundred of comments, I've just did some more homework and found another way: when I click a tab and do a request with AJAX

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea, and was what i was going to suggest if you had a lot of data, but a few hundred results isnt much - i would just write the simple (single query, indexed array) code and then actually test it to see if it was slow, it probably will be fine

Comment: If you need to, you could also do AJAX pagination. You load the first page only and then the user can go to the next page and you just send an offset or something to the server. If the data is being displayed in tables (doesn't sound like it), you could possibly use the AJAX functionality of DataTables to make that easier.